# Equals method not working

Tags: java, arrays, object, equals

I am  a new Java programmer , im trying to implement a method to check the equality between two "features" array inside my object "FeatureVector"
seems really basic but the method is not working for some reason ; it doesnt produce logical results ,and i cant seem to find a solution, please help

```
public boolean equals (FeatureVector x )
{
    boolean result =false ; 
    boolean size = false ;
    for (int i =0 ; (i < this.features.length && result == true );i ++  )
    {
        if (this.features[i] == x.features[i] ) {result = true ;}
        else {result = false ; }
    }

    if (this.features.length == x.features.length ) {size = true ;}
    else {size =false; }
    return (result && size) ; 
}
```

Comment: What is contained in the features array? Strings? ints?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't produce logical results"?  Can you give an example?  My guess would be that you need to test equality of the array items with their own `.equals` method, not `==`.

Answer (score 6):

The bug in the initial code was initializing `result` to `false`. That caused the loop to exit immediately, before the first comparison.

Note that it's considered a less-than-best practice to compare boolean values to `true` and `false`. At best, it's redundant. At worst, you're likely to create an error that's hard to spot:

```
if (some_value = false) {  // DON'T do this -- it's always false!
```

I've suggested before that, if you absolutely *must* do this, perhaps due to an undiagnosed psychological condition or a tech lead who should really have been in management, protect yourself by using Yoda conditions:

```
if (false == some_value) {  // Syntax error, a single "=" will create.
```

---

Here's a corrected and optimized version of the original code:

```
public boolean equals (FeatureVector x) {

  // Do the "cheapest" test first, so you have an opportunity to return
  // without waiting for the loop to run.
  if (this.features.length != x.features.length) {
     return false;
  }

  // There's no need to "accumulate" the results of each comparison
  // because  you can return immediately when a mismatch is detected.
  for (int i = 0; i < this.features.length; i++) {
    if (this.features[i] != x.features[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should switch the order of comparing the length and comparing the individual features: if the lengths are different, there's no point of comparing the rest!

You should also return `false` as soon as you know there's a difference - again, the only reason to continue with the loop is if you think that you may return `true`.

Here is how you can change your program:

```
public boolean equals (FeatureVector x )
{
    if (this.features.length != x.features.length ) {
        return false;
    }
    // If we get here, the sizes are the same:
    for (int i = 0 ; i < this.features.length ; i++)
    {
        if (this.features[i] != x.features[i] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // If we got here, the sizes are the same, and all elements are also the same:
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things that could go wrong with your logic. I'll rewrite it and comment as I go along.

```
public boolean equals (FeatureVector x )
{

    /*
     * Check for the length first, if the lengths don't match then
     * you don't have to bother checking each elements. Saves time!
     */
    if (this.features.length != x.features.length) return false;

    for (int i =0 ; i < this.features.length; i++) {
        /*
         * As soon as you find a mismatching element, return out of the
         * loop and method, no need to keep checking. Saves time!
         */
        if (this.features[i] != x.features[i]) return false;
    }

    // If the logic makes it this far, then all elements are equal
    return true;
}
```